# Should Cloudera Manager 5 be installed on a compute node, or on a standalone server?

Tags: cloudera, cloudera-manager

I'm installing a small cloud (10 nodes) using the free Cloudera Manager.  Should I dedicate a server to Cloudera Manager, or can it be installed on one of the compute nodes?  What's the best practice?  I have an extra server to install the manager on, if that is a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you should include the Cloudera Manager host itself in your cloud.

In the Cloudera Manager installer, it says:

> Cloudera recommends including Cloudera Manager server's host because it is often used for the Cloudera Management Service. This will also enable health monitoring for that host.