# Where shall I put Cloudera Manager Server

Tags: ubuntu, hadoop, cloudera, cloudera-manager

I have a cluster of 4 ubuntu 12.04 LTS, preparing for installing Hadoop by leveraging Cloudera Manager (with CDH5).

But I am confused about where to put the Cloudera Manager Server.

Shall I add a new ubuntu machine to host the Cloudera Manager Server, then let it manage the Hadoop cluster consists of 1 master, 3 slaves?

Or shall I put the Cloudera Manager Server along with Hadoop master? So the Hadoop master and Cloudera Manager Server is on one (virtual) machine.

This question may be duplicated [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21081874/should-cloudera-manager-5-be-installed-on-a-compute-node-or-on-a-standalone-ser). But after seeing it, I am still confused.

Looking forward to any expertise.

Answer (score 1):

In fact it depends on your requirements. You have to know that Cloudera Manager consumes some ressources on the machine. So if you want to dedicate all your vms power to Hadoop you should use another machine to just host Cloudera Manager.
But, you can put Cloudera Manager in a machine which host others services. It will not provok any problem.

Personnaly, I installed Cloudera Manager services on the secondary NameNode. And of course, to acess to the Cloudera Manager console, you will use : hostip:7180 where hostip is the ip of the machine where Cloudera Manager is installed.

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! About the SecondaryNameNode, shall I run it on a separate machine? Seems that you know the secret of this.

Comment: You can put the SecondaryNameNode on the same machine than the NameNode but there is no interest. The SecondaryNameNode is the back-up of the Namenode if this last crashes. But you can aswell set up your cluster without SecondaryNameNode. My own set-up is very close to yours. In fact I have 5 machines : 1 with NameNode + master role for HDFS / Hive / Hbase + Cloudera Manager, 1 SecondaryNamenode for the back-up and the last three are DataNode.